# This dependency was not found: *swiper/vue how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I'm scratching my head because I ran `npm i swiper` and read through the Swiper Vue docs and it says to `import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue` which I've done and I even get the bundle size showing `95.4K (gzipped: 28.9K)`.

When I run `npm run serve` I then get this error

```
This dependency was not found:

* swiper/vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save swiper/vue
```

I for the life of me cannot figure out how to import that dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the swiper version 7* then you could face this type of issue.

[Github issue 4871](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871)

Try downgrading to the v6.7.5 , see if that helps.

[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961500/swiper-dependency-was-not-found-typescript-ionic-vue)

Comment: I read deeper into Swiper's GitHub issues after I posted this, and this definitely is the fix! Thank you for the response 

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, using Vue ^3.0.0 and Swiper ^8.0.6

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue/swiper-vue";

import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
```

Comment: It helped me, using Vue 3 and Swiper 8.0.7